# cin.get() causing "no instance of overloaded function" error

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I'm having a bit of issues with a C++ Project that I'm working on for a class. I keep getting an error message stating 'no instance of overloaded function'. I did some googling and it seems that everyone says that this error is caused by passing a string into the cin.get() function, but I'm using this function with a char, not a string. Visual Studio says the error is at: "cin.get(nameFull);" but I've defined nameFull as a char, not a string. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
        const int MONTHS = 12;
        const int RETRO_MONTHS = 6;

        char nameFull[30];      // INPUT - Employee's full name
        float salaryCurrent;    // INPUT - Current annual salary
        float percentIncrease;  // INPUT - Percent increase due
        float salaryNew;        // OUTPUT - New salary after increase
        float salaryMonthly;    // OUTPUT - New monthly salary
        float retroactivePay;   // OUTPUT - Retroactive pay due employee
        int count;              // CALC - Counter for loop

        for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
            cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
            cin.get(nameFull);
            cout << "What is your current salary?" << endl;
            cin >> salaryCurrent;
            cout << "What is your pay increase?" << endl;
            cin >> percentIncrease;

            salaryNew = salaryCurrent + (salaryCurrent * percentIncrease);
            salaryMonthly = salaryNew / MONTHS;
            retroactivePay = (salaryNew - salaryCurrent) * RETRO_MONTHS;

            cout << nameFull << "'s SALARY INFORMATION" << endl;

            cout << "New Salary"
                << setw(20) << "Monthly Salary"
                << setw(20) << "Retroactive Pay" << endl;

            cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(10) << salaryNew
                << setw(20) << salaryMonthly
                << setw(20) << retroactivePay << endl;

            cout << "<Press enter to continue>" << endl << endl;
            cin.get();
        }
        return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `getline (cin, nameFull);`? (though better to make `nameFull` type `std::string`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nameFull` is an array of `char` (more specifically `char[30]`) which decays to a pointer to character (`char*`). There is no overload of `std::istream::get` which accepts a single pointer to character, but there *is* one that accepts a pointer + the size of the buffer that you would like to read into.

So all you need to do is pass an additional parameter:

```
cin.get(nameFull, 30);
```